# Google ClientLogin Authorization and Google Music

Tags: c#, web-services, authentication, httpwebrequest

I am playing around with Google Music. I'm trying to see if I can write an app that will stream my music files uploaded to Google Music. So far, I've managed to authenticate myself using ClientLogin and access the music.google.com page. However, whenever I try to access http://music.google.com/music/services/loadalltracks, the page that contains all of my tracks in JSON format, I get a 401: Unauthorized error. However, if I pass the cookies containing SID and HSID, it works and I can access the page.

Does anyone know why It doesn't work with ClientLogin, outside of Google not supporting it with Music? Have you had similiar experience with other Google Services? In the event I can't get ClientLogin to work, is there anyway to work around it, using the SID? I don't know how the HSID is generated.

Comment: I wrote a class in php for Google Calendar. To authenticate I also used ClientLogin. But to access the service I only needed the "Auth" authorization cookie. The token needed to be added to the headers to access the service.
Maybe this helps : 
http://code.google.com/intl/nl/apis/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps.html

Comment: Yeah, that's how I'm doing it. It works for getting me in to the main Music page, but not for the pages to request the tracks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, as far as I can tell the reason sending the SID and HSID cookies makes the request work is because you're simulating the way a normal user is accessing the service.
You can't go the regular application way because that's not supported in google music (as far as my internet research showed, there's no API for google music).

Oh, and one thing: google discourages people from using ClientLogin and instead tells people to use OAuth ("ClientLogin [is] Google's proprietary authorization API ... you should avoid using [this] service." found at http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/auth/overview.html) so in the future you might want to use that. Maybe it'll even work in this case (It sends a different token from ClientLogin - OAuth token instead of an Auth token) though I doubt that.

Anyway, I hope this cleared things up.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like there are no valid scopes I can use for Google Music. I guess I'll have to wait and hope they release an api for it.

Answer (score 9):

Since there is no official api for Google Music, you need full SSO credentials to use those endpoints. The easiest way to do this is to emulate a browser (with eg mechanize).

The way my [unofficial Google Music api](https://github.com/simon-weber/Unofficial-Google-Music-API) accomplishes this is a bit cleaner, but more work: use clientlogin to authenticate to the Music Manager service, then upgrade those credentials using tokenauth. This isn't really a public feature, but it's described by a third party [here](http://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2012/11/sso-using-account-manager.html), and by a Google design doc [here](http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/chromiumos-design-docs/login). The specific endpoints you need are in my code [here](https://github.com/simon-weber/Unofficial-Google-Music-API/tree/421bbc4007f1d60fd4d10f902be73a0efbb6c3af/gmusicapi/utils) (in clientlogin.py and tokenauth.py).

You'll want to send `u=0` and `xt=[value of xt cookie]` in the querystring as well. The first argument specifies which account you're using (if you're signed into multiple), and the second is a xsrf token.